# Callback method setting lightning combobox to previously selected item

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created a `text input box` and a dependent `lightning-combobox`. When user inputs `acc` in text input box, it iterates over a list (fetched from custom obejct in `connectedcallback()` method) and filters out items which contains `acc` substring. This filtered list gets displayed in combobox and user selects a item with label `Account`. When the user clears out the input provided in text box, this filtered list also gets cleared along with the selected item `Account`.Till here, it is working as expected.

Now,When the user again types in `a`character in text input box, combobox is automatically gets set to previous selected item `Account`.

I inspected the code and found that the in `aura:proddebug.js`, below code gets executed and then combobox is getting set to `Account`. This should not happen and combobox should get cleared out.

```
for (let i = 0, len = callbacks.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  callbacks[i]();
}
```

`HTML` :

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Select Report">
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        <lightning-input
            name="enter-search"
            label="Search "
            type="text"
            onchange={handleSearchChange}
        ></lightning-input>
    </p>
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        <lightning-combobox
        name="Report List"
        label="Report List"
        value={value}
        placeholder="select report"
        options={reports}
        onchange={handleSelectReportChange}></lightning-combobox>
    </p></lightning-card>
    </template>
```

`JS`:

```
export default class LWCcreateannouncement extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
@track reportId;
@track reports=[];
@track disableButton = true;
@track error;
allreports=[];

connectedCallback() {
    getReportList()
    .then((result) => {
        this.allreports = result.map((report) => ({ label:report.Name, value:report.Id}));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error; 
    });    
}

handleSearchChange(event) {
    const allReports = this.allreports;
    const searchTerm = event.target.value; 
    if(searchTerm){
        this.reports = allReports.filter(str => {
            return str.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        });
    } else {   
        this.reportId = '';
        this.reports = [];  
        this.disableButton = true;
    }  

}

handleSelectReportChange(event) {
    this.reportId = event.detail.value;
    if(this.reportId) {
        this.disableButton = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaging the **value={value}** property of the Combobox with **value={reportId}**

I think this should solve the problem as you are blanking **this.reportId** when you clear the search input.

Comment: yeah this will do, Thanks! I completely missed this rather simple part.

Comment: But, do you know why this callback method getting executed

Comment: Hello, I have no idea of why.